# Need to fix JavaScript so that the array begins at the right position

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hi I have got a jsFiddle to share but never used it before so I hope I did it right..
http://jsfiddle.net/Mayron/3V62C/

I also have these screen shot to better show what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efqjp.jpg

I have a table of images in the gallery page and when you click on an image it opens up a frame that shows a blank but much larger image which gains the source of the smaller image you  clicked on. That works fine but I have all the images in the gallery listed in an array and the large frame has three buttons on it: previous, close and next. So far the JavaScript code allows you to click next and previous to go through them but it always begins the journey from  array[0] and that is no good if you click to view the 6th one in the list from the gallery page first for example.

I hope that makes sense if not then let me know!

The issue is with this line that causes it to begin from the first image:

```
currentIndex = 0;
```

How can I change this so that the currentIndex number is the image that the user first clicks on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways but that really depends on what you use and how clean you want your code to look. I put a hidden input in each of my divs and retrieve it with JQuery's `$("input", $(this).parent()).val();`

You could also use Jquery's index. http://api.jquery.com/index/

You could have it in a class and retrieve the class of the clicked item (same idea as having an ID for each image)

On click you can have a selector added in the class attribute then you can use a for-each to count how many images go through before you hit that class in your image order.

You could also do showLarge(this, index#) and set the index that way. I cannot get your JS fiddle to work though.

---

Do this for every image line:

```
    <td><a href="#" onclick="javaScript:showLarge(this,1);" ><img class="imgBorder" id="image1"  src="Media//Gallery//img_1.jpg" alt="Gallery Image 1" /></a>
    </td>
```

This puts onclick in anchor tag and adds an id in the image tag named image1 (1 is the number you put in the anchor tag 2nd param)

In javascript, do:

```
function showLarge(img, index) {
    var largeFrame = document.getElementById("zoomedIn");
    largeFrame.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var largeImage = document.getElementById("largeImage");
    src = document.getElementById("image"+index);
    largeImage.src = src.src;
    currentImage = index;

}
```

This gets the image by id according to index clicked

For the next+prev button do:

```
function changeImage(direction) {
    index = parseInt(currentIndex) + parseInt(direction);

    if (index < 1) {
        index = 1; // or use imgArray.length to rotate round
    }

    if (index > imgArray.length) {
        index = imgArray.length; // or use 0 to rotate round
    }
    src = document.getElementById("image"+index);
    document.getElementById('largeImage').src = src.src;
    currentIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: thank you but I do not know how to use jquery yet since I am trying to learn JavaScript and it is for a college assignment which is due in soon lol

Comment: Then use the very last line which requires no JQuery at all.

Comment: I am trying to use your idea but I am really struggling. I cannot get JS Fiddle to work either but would it help if I could give you my files? http://www.mediafire.com/download/xibb998x4yg5avc/Image+JavaScript+Array+help%21.zip

Comment: Put your onclick in the <a> tag, your code wont work but maybe try putting it on http://liveweave.com/ since jsfiddle wont call your showLarge function from the HTML to the JS

Comment: Thank you but the next button and previous buttons are the things I need help with as they next -1 or +1 to the image array correctly :(

Comment: updated for that function too (put 1 instead of 0 because I put 1 in the example above)

Comment: I have changed each line like you said and have changed the "1" to the line number: <td><a href="#zoomedIn" onclick="javaScript:showLarge(this,3);" ><img class="imgBorder" id="image3"  src="Media//Gallery//img_3.png" alt="Gallery Image 3" /></a></td> is that correct? Ans I have added your 2 functions but now the next and previous buttons do nothing

Comment: well I dont know why you do #zoomedIn, just do # since it does nothing anyways. It should work however. At least, does the image open correctly?

Does firebug give you any errors?

Comment: I do #zoomedIn just so the page moves up to a better position to see the large image frame easier. It is nothing too important. No idea what firebug is (still a beginner) but will look into it tomorrow. spent 12 hours on this today and its going no where but thanks

Comment: Firebug is an addon for firefox that makes website creation 100x easier because it writes errors in a console.

Comment: I get the following:

    ReferenceError: currentIndex is not defined
    [Break On This Error]  
    
    index = parseInt(currentIndex) + parseInt(direction);

So I changed currentIndex to currentImage which then results in the below error:

    TypeError: src is null
    [Break On This Error]  
    
    document.getElementById('largeImage').src = src.src;

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING! I had to rewrite it all my own way while still using your idea with flicking them through with the ID numbers. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function findIndex(src) {
    for (i = 0; i = imgArray.length; i++)
        if (imgArray[i].src == src) {
            currentIndex = i;
            return;
        }
}
function showLarge(img) {
    var largeFrame = document.getElementById("zoomedIn");
    largeFrame.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var largeImage = document.getElementById("largeImage");
    largeImage.src = img.src;
    findIndex(img.src);
}
```

It will update the currentIndex value.
I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RN4bN/
But I can't run it, so try directly on your code.

Comment: hmm still does not seem to work. The order becomes messy once again :/

Comment: Could you put a working example which reproduce the error on jsfiddle pls ? With this one javascripts functions are undefined.

Comment: Not really sure how to use that jsFiddle because what ever code I put onto it I do not know where the errors show up and the result panel never works either :/ However I think its because your code is still using "currentIndex = 0;" from the jsFiddle so its putting out the same result as I mentioned in the original post

Comment: in my findIndex function, change currentIndex to currentImage

Comment: When I click on the 4th image (array[3]) in the table and press next it just shows the 2nd array (the 2nd image) like it did originally. It should show the 5th image (array[4])

Comment: I really can't do more without a working example...
You can see the errors in jsfiddle in the javascript console.
And you can include file in the left panel

Comment: What about if I give you the files you need in a zip folder? Would that help? Then you can see exactly what I mean: http://www.mediafire.com/?xibb998x4yg5avc

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID on each of them which is the number of it from the array, then when it is clicked change the currentIndex to that.